# Storm - Writing to HDFS using compression

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-storm

I want to store all my raw data incoming in my storm topology in a HDFS cluster.
This is JSON or binary data, incoming at a rate of 2k / secs.

I was trying to use the HDFS bolt ([http://storm.apache.org/releases/0.10.0/storm-hdfs.htmlà](http://storm.apache.org/releases/0.10.0/storm-hdfs.html%C3%A0) , but it does not allow compression using the normal hdfs bolt
Compression is only possible using the Sequence File Bolt.
I don’t want to use sequence file, as I don’t have a real key.

Plus, I have already Cassandra for storing my key / value stuff and serving my request.
It just take too much disk (overhead) using Cassandra for my raw data (not this post objective to debate about this).

Can anyone help me with that ? 
I can use the java Hadoop driver client to achieve that ? 
Have anyone a code snippet of that ?

Comment: Not that i would recommend Sequence Files but lack of key should not stop you. You can use NullWritable as the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay there is no way to compress on the fly like I wanted.
But I have found a solution, I share it here if someone need it.

This problem is not only relative to Storm but it is a more general Hadoop question.

All my data are writted using the HdfsBolt :

```
    RecordFormat format = new DelimitedRecordFormat().withFieldDelimiter("|");

    //Synchronize data buffer with the filesystem every 1000 tuples
    // Need to be configurable
    SyncPolicy syncPolicy = new CountSyncPolicy(1000);

    // Rotate data files when they reach five MB
    // need to be configuration
    FileRotationPolicy rotationPolicy = new FileSizeRotationPolicy(10.0f, FileSizeRotationPolicy.Units.MB);

    // Use default, Storm-generated file names
    FileNameFormat fileNameFormat = new DefaultFileNameFormat().withPath("/datadir/in_progress") ;

    // Instantiate the HdfsBolt
    HdfsBolt bolt = new HdfsBolt()
        .withFsUrl("hdfs://"+dfsHost+":"+dfsPort)
        .withFileNameFormat(fileNameFormat)
        .withRecordFormat(format)
        .withRotationPolicy(rotationPolicy)
        .withSyncPolicy(syncPolicy)
        .addRotationAction(new MoveFileAction().withDestination("/datadir/finished"));
```

This is giving me one file per executor of my bolt.. Not easy to handle but it's okay :)

Then I schedule automatic compression using hadoop streaming (in a cron on namenode or something like this) :

```
    hadoop jar share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.3.jar \
        -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=0 \
        -Dmapred.output.compress=true \
        -Dmapred.compress.map.output=true \
        -Dmapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec \
        -input /datadir/finished \
        -output /datadir/archives \
        -mapper /bin/cat \
        -inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat \
        -outputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat
```

Here I still have one issue : 
One input file is compress into one archive.
So my 10MB input file (each for one worker) is compressing into one gzip (or bzip) of  1MB -> this is producing so many small files, and it's a problem in hadoop

To solve this issue, i will try to look at the hadoop archive (HAR) functionnality.

I also need to purge already compressed files in /datadir/finished

Hope I will have feedbacks from you guys
Keep in touch

Regards,
Bastien